# How to unpack a tuple from org-sbe evaluating a python code block into multiple columns of a org-table?

Tags: org-mode, python, org-table, literate-programming

I often encounter situations where I can easily think of python code that, given some input values, computes multiple output values at once.  As an example, consider the following simple code-block that converts the real and imaginary part (a and b) of a complex number to its polar representation (radius and phase).  In an org-mode file I would write:

```
#+name: radius_phase_conv 
#+begin_src python :exports none :var a=2. :var b=2.
  from cmath import polar
  from math import degrees
  num = complex(a,b)
  r, phi = polar(num)
  phi_deg = degrees(phi)
  return round(r,5), round(phi_deg,5)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: radius_phase_conv
| 2.82843 | 45.0 |
```

Now I want to use such a code on a table in org-mode that contains the columns with the input values.  In above example, we might have a table with a and b.

```
|      a |       b | 
|--------+---------|
|      1 |       0 | 
|      1 |       1 |
```

Putting the line

```
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-sbe "radius_phase_conv" (a $1) (b $2)
```

below the table, will produce a 3rd column that contains the tuples with the radius and the phase.

```
|      a |       b |                    |
|--------+---------+--------------------|
|      1 |       0 | (1.0 0.0)          |
|      1 |       1 | (1.41421 45.0)     |
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-sbe "radius_phase_conv" (a $1) (b $2))
```

How do I need to alter the `#+TBLFM:` + `org-sbe` statement in order to produce two columns in the final table, i.e. the desired result would be

```
| a | b |          |       |
|---+---+----------+-------|
| 1 | 0 | 1.0      |  0.0  |
| 1 | 1 | 1.41421  | 45.0  |
#+TBLFM: ???
```

Answer (score 1):

How about breaking it into two functions and have

`$3='(org-sbe radius...)::$4='(org-sbe phase...)`

Or keeping one function but passing in a 3rd argument that tells it what value you want returned? Not ideal...

Or don't use `TBLFM`? What about calling `radius_phase_conv` and passing in the `a|b` table (after you `NAME` it), and then having Python print out the four-column table for you?

Comment: Breaking it into two functions is what I use at the moment, but it is not elegant, since I have to duplicate code that does essentially the same.  The second solution is what I used in the past,  but it is also not very elegant, as I will have column a and b occurring twice in the org-file, i.e. if I want to change a value in a or b, I have to do it in another table.